# CakePHP 4: Form validation callback executes when it's not supposed to

Tags: php, cakephp

everyone. I have two fields in a form, one dropdown and one text:

```
echo $this->Form->control('label_id', ['label' => 'Sensitivity Label', 'empty' => true, 'options' => $labels]);
      
echo $this->Form->control('distro_notes', ['label' => 'Distribution Notes (Required if a PROPRIETARY or CONFIDENTIAL label is chosen)']);
```

Field `distro_notes` is only required if certain label types are chosen from the dropdown. There are six available, and `distro_notes` is not required for the first two. My validation rule looks like this:

```
$validator
    ->notEmptyString('distro_notes', 'This field is required if a PROPRIETARY or CONFIDENTIAL label is chosen', function ($context) {
        $labelIds = [1,2];
        return !in_array($context['data']['label_id'], $labelIds) && empty($context['data']['distro_notes']);
    });
```

So the validation should only execute when the chosen label ID is 3,4,5, or 6 AND when `distro_notes` is empty, but it executes in *all* cases. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The callback function in a validator should only return *when* to run this validator, not define the rules for validation. Per the function definition:

```
 * @param bool|string|callable $when Indicates when the field is not allowed
 *   to be empty. Valid values are false (never), 'create', 'update'. If a
 *   callable is passed then the field will be required to be not empty when
 *   the callback returns true.
```

If you want the `distro_notes` field to be not empty only when a `label_id` is *not* 1 or 2, then you should just define that much in the callback:

```
$validator->notEmptyString('distro_notes',
    'This field is required if a PROPRIETARY or CONFIDENTIAL label is chosen',
    function ($context) {
        $labelIds = [1, 2];

        return !in_array($context['data']['label_id'], $labelIds);
    });
```

This way, if `label_id` is 1 or 2, the function returns `false` when label_id is 1 or 2, and then the validator is not run (in other words, if label_id is 1 or 2 then distro_notes can be empty). And then if `label_id` is any other value (3,4,5,6) then `distro_notes` is required and cannot be empty.

Comment: That didn't change the behavior; however, explicitly defining the *allowed* values in an array (3,4,5,6) and testing for `in_array` did. Not sure why. The way it's written above should work, too.